# Spring SecurityContext is null on page not found error

Tags: spring, security, error-handling

Springs returns null from `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();` on handling eror 404 (when not mapped url entered). But it works fine on exceptions(500) or security errors(403, [Spring SecurityContext returning null authentication on error pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6305801)) thanks to ExceptionTranslationFilter.
Why is this happening and what i can change to obtains security context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by storing user principal in session attributes.