# Null authentication when error handling 403

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-spring-security

I'm running now Grails 3.1.15 with `org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:3.1.1`.

When I return a status code `403` my `ErrorController` should generate an appropriate error page (this is mapped in `UrlMappings`). It requires a `springSecurityService.currentUser` to generate that error page.

Turns out that I get `NPE` in that process since `springSecurityService.currentUser` is null as well as the authentication object.

This was working fine in Grails2 and the `v2` of `spring-security-plugin`.

I've encountered this question: [Spring SecurityContext returning null authentication on error pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6305801/spring-securitycontext-returning-null-authentication-on-error-pages) and the suggestion there is that the `ExceptionTranslationFilter` has to be in place. 
In Grails2 it is indeed in place but in Grails3 it was replaced/extended with `UpdateRequestContextHolderExceptionTranslationFilter` - it's still in the filter chain.

What can I do to prevent that from happening (getting a null authentication) when error handling a `403`

Remarks:

- the whole situations happens only in production env when deployed in Tomcat - not reproducible in dev mode

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting this in application.yml?  This has helped me in both Grails 2 and Grails 3.

```
grails:
    plugin:
        springsecurity:
            adh:
                errorPage: null
```